# aws lambda: invoke with payload from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm trying to invoke my lambda using aws cli:

```
$ aws lambda invoke \
    --function-name soc-update-dynamodb-java \
    --invocation-type Event \
    --payload file://invoke-payload.json \
   response.json
```

However, I'm getting this message:

> An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x28
>    at [Source: (byte[])"E�(�����U�슉���ޞԨ��k.....

`payload.json` content is a s3 event-like json:

```
{
"Records": [
  {
    "eventVersion": "2.0",
    "eventSource": "aws:s3",
    "awsRegion": "eu-central-1",
    "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
    "userIdentity": {
      "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
    },
    "requestParameters": {
      "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "responseElements": {
      "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
      "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
    },
    "s3": {
      "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
      "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
      "bucket": {
        "name": "soc-connect",
        "ownerIdentity": {
          "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
        },
        "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example"
      },
      "object": {
        "key": "example.key",
        "size": 1024,
        "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
        "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

I'm able to execute it from aws web console using this event, but I have problem trying to invoke it using aws cli.

I've get encoding from invoke-payload.json:

```
$ file -i invoke-payload.json 
invoke-payload.json: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

As you can see, encoding is `us-ascii`.

**EDIT**

I've also tried to send payload embedded on command. As you can see on image, I'm getting the same message:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It works on my end. But they I just copied and pasted the json from SO. Thus I think your original file must have some strange characters somewhere.

Comment: I've edited post with more details of sending payload on command line.

Comment: What shell is this? And can you give the output of `echo $LC_CTYPE`?

Comment: I've performed `$ echo $LC_CTYPE -> en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: How was this JSON generated? Is this JSON copied from somewhere, from different Operating System?

Answer (score 33):

use the fileb:// ("file binary") syntax for the payload parameter so you don't have to run it through base64

...
--payload fileb://invoke-payload.json

Comment: Article from AWS explaining what file and fileb are: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/best-practices-for-local-file-parameters/

Answer (score 19):

#### Invoke Lambda with simple JSON from the CLI

Here's how to test your Lambda by giving it a short JSON payload, and displaying the result in the terminal:

```
aws lambda invoke \
--payload '{"beer": "tasty"}' --function-name myfunc \
--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
/dev/stdout
```

*Building on [antklim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056532/9664)*

Comment: With awscli v2, the payload needs to base64-encoded. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64922434/271415).

Answer (score 15):

For AWS CLI version 2 add `--cli-binary-format` flag to make sure the payload interpreted correctly.

```
$ aws lambda invoke \
    --function-name soc-update-dynamodb-java \
    --invocation-type Event \
    --payload file://invoke-payload.json \
    --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
    response.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, when payload is with multiple JSON fields, I had after the comma (,) a **space** and failed to be processed.
BAD:

```
--payload {\"param1\":\"abc\", \"param2\":\"xyz\"}
```

GOOD:

```
--payload {\"param1\":\"abc\",\"param2\":\"xyz\"}
```