# aws cli lambda-Could not parse request body into json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have created aws lambda function in .net core and deployed.
I have tried executing function in aws console with test case and its working. but i am not able achieve the same with cli command

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name "mylambda" --log-type Tail --payload file://D:/Files/lamdainputfile.json file://D:/Files/response.txt
```

i got getting error with cli command

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 138)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"�zn�]t�zn�m�"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I tried passing json

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name "mylambda" --log-type Tail --payload "{'input1':'100', 'input2':'200'}" file://D:/Files/response.txt
```

but it's not working

This lambda function is executing aws console with test case and giving correct result. I have added same input in local json file and tried with cli command.

Json input:

```
{
  "input1": "100",
  "input2": "200"
}
```

EDIT:

After correction in inline json i am getting error for output file

```
Unknown options: file://D:/Files/response.txt
```

is there any command to print output in cli only?

Comment: The inline json should be `--payload '{"input1":"100", "input2":"200"}'`.

Comment: Thanks,@Marcin, i have modified inline json , i am getting error for output file..pls check updated question..

Comment: Instead of `file://D:/Files/response.txt` it should be `D:/Files/response.txt` I think.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The documentation is not updated from the cli version 1. For the aws cli version 2 we need to base64 encode the payload.

Mac:

```
payload=`echo '{"input1": 100, "input2": 200 }' | openssl base64`
aws lambda invoke --function-name myfunction --payload "$payload" SomeOutFile &
```

Comment: Why do we need & at the end of the last command? It yields some strange number.

Comment: Also works on my Windows 10 in Git Bash, without last &

Comment: how did you find this ? is there an other way than reverse engineering it ?

Answer (score 15):

Adding the option `--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out` will allow you to pass raw json in the invoke command.

```sh
aws lambda invoke \
    --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
    --function-name "mylambda" \
    --payload '{"input1": "100", "input2": "200"}' \
    file://D:/Files/response.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [ASW CLI invoke command options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#options) `--payload` only accepts inline blob arguments (i.e. JSON). In other words `--payload` parameter can not be used to read input from a file, so `--payload file://D:/Files/lamdainputfile.json` will not work.

In the example provided what probably happens is `--payload` is ignored, `file://D:/Files/lamdainputfile.json` is treated as `<outfile>`, and an error is raised for `file://D:/Files/response.txt` as it is an unexpected positional argument.
What is required is reading the contents of `D:/Files/lamdainputfile.json` with a separate command. How this can be done is different based on the type of shell used. Bash example:

```sh
aws lambda invoke --payload "$(cat /path/to/input.json)" ...
```

Original answer:

I don't know about the first case (`--payload file:///...`), however the second case is not a valid JSON, as JSON requires strings to be double quoted. Try the following JSON:

```
{
    "input": "100",
    "input2": "200"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have modified inline json , i am getting error for output file..pls check updated question